# Swift - Error: CGContextSetStrokePattern: pattern specified with non-pattern color space

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an image pattern along a line. Eventually, I would like to turn this into a pencil texture for a drawing app, but for now I am just testing out the pattern along a simple line. When I run it, I'm getting a solid black line, and the console prints this message:

Error: CGContextSetStrokePattern: pattern specified with non-pattern color space.

```
func drawStroke(view: UIView, context: CGContext?) {

    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0


    let callbacks:CGPatternCallbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(
        version: 0,
        drawPattern:  { (pointer, context) -> Void in
            //let PENCIL = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Pencil_Texture.png")!)

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, patternImage.CGColor)

            CGContextAddArc(context, 3, 3, 4, 0, radians(360), 0)
            CGContextFillPath(context)

        },releaseInfo: nil)

    CGContextSaveGState(context)



    let space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let patternSpace:CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(space)!
    CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, patternSpace)

    let pattern:CGPatternRef = CGPatternCreate(nil, view.frame, CGAffineTransformIdentity, 24, 24, .ConstantSpacing, true,[ callbacks ])!

    let alpha:CGFloat = 1.0


    //line
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
    //points
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, view.center.x, view.center.y)
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, view.center.x, view.center.y, view.center.x, view.center.y + 200)

    // Draw the stroke
    CGContextSetStrokePattern(context, pattern, [alpha])
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

I've looked through Apple's documentation, but it's not much help. I've seen some tutorials in Objective-C but I think certain Obj-C methods don't exist in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use Stencil (Uncolored) Patterns

You need change 2 mistake in your code

1/ CGPatternCreate function: set **isColored** parameter pass **False**, because you using uncolored

```
let pattern:CGPatternRef = CGPatternCreate(nil, view.frame, CGAffineTransformIdentity, 24, 24, .ConstantSpacing, false,[callbacks])!
```

2/ So important, you draw a stroke path, so that you need set ColorSpace and StrokePattern in Stroke following.

```
let color1: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(context, patternSpace)
CGContextSetStrokePattern(context, pattern, color1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.1**
The api's have been changed in Swift 3 so the here is the code for Swift 3.1

This code is for **uncoloured** pattern ( When you specify 'false' for parameter 'isColored' in CGPattern( ..., isColored: false, ... ) )

```
    let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    if let patternSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpace(patternBaseSpace: colorSpace) {
            ctx.setFillColorSpace(patternSpace)
         // ... rest of the code
    }
```

This code is for **coloured** pattern ( When you specify 'true' for parameter 'isColored' in CGPattern( ..., isColored: false, ... ) )

```
        if let patternSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpace(patternBaseSpace: nil) {
                ctx.setFillColorSpace(patternSpace)
             // ... rest of the code
        }
```